# Commerce configuration files CD server

Tags: configuration, sitecore-commerce, commerce-engine

What files from Commerce should be enabled/disabled on a Content Delivery server.
I can see all files from folder : **App_Config\Include\Y.Commerce.Engine** use a rule-based configuration like :

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/" xmlns:role="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/role/">
  <sitecore role:require="Standalone or ContentDelivery or ContentManagement">
```

But the file from \App_Config\Include\Z.Commerce.Engine\ doesn't contain rule based configuration.

Also the files from Include folder doesn't contain rules based configuration.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think in the next future release Sitecore Team will update all configs with rule-based configuration (if it necessary of course).

Sitecore provides installation only for standalone on-premise configuration and no any documentation how you can configure Sitecore Commerce 9 for CD environment.

From my point of view, you should try to use the same commerce configs on CD environment, but if you will have any issues there - you need to contact Sitecore Support.

All these configs contains some configuration for DI and pipelines. Feeling that all of them are also required for CD environment